Xorg Running on Nvidia GPU, but GUI not starting
New here, but not super new to Linux or Mint.
I just can't get my Xorg to start on my current display even though I see that Xorg is running on my GPU via nvidia-smi.
I've tried running inxi -G and had a problem there where nvidia drivers were running on amdgpu as my system is a Dell Alienware m18 R1 with an AMD Ryzen 9 7945HX with integrated graphics and an RTX 4090 Laptop. I fixed this by blacklisting amdgpu, but I still have no GUI.
I've tried installing drivers many times using "Driver Manager" and apt to no avail. I've also blacklisted nouveau and updated GRUB settings but still nothing. Either I use the GUI without Nvidia drivers or use the GPU in tty mode.
Secure boot is off, the kernel version is 6+ on Linux Mint 21.3 Cinnamon desktop, and the drivers are set up properly, and Xorg is running. Though after booting $DISPLAY is not set, but after setting it (using ~/.bashrc maybe not correct), running a command like xeyes still doesn't work or show anything in CTRL + ALT + F7, where I expect the GUI to be.
This is very frustrating and putting me behind in my work since I need the GUI for VSCode but obviously need GPU access. I've been stuck for over 5 days with constant YouTube/StackOverflow/This Forum, so help would be extremely appreciated.
